# Android : References to a Context and memory leaks

Tags: android, android-context

I've read that it is a mistake and a source of memory leaks in Android application to keep a long-lived references to a Context.

But I don't understand if it is ok to create a class that looks like this one:

```
public class HelperClass {
    private Context context;

    public HelperClass(Context context) {
        this.context = context;
    }
    public void myHelperMethod() {
        // uses this.context
    }
}
```

And call it from an Activity:

```
public class MyActivity extends Activity {
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        HelperClass h = new HelperClass(this);
        h.myHelperMethod();
    }

    ...
}
```

Answer (score 53, accepted):

This is fine, and will not cause a memory leak.

As soon as `onCreate` finishes executing, `h` will be out of scope and become eligible for garbage collection.  If `h` was static, then you would run into problems.  Only when the reference to the context outlives the lifecycle of the context itself will a memory leak occur.  A few helpful hints:

- Use `Context.getApplicationContext()` when possible.  This context will live as long as your application is alive.
- Be careful when using static fields and inner classes.
- [Run your application through a profiler](http://discuz-android.blogspot.com/2009/06/android-memory-usage-with-hprof.html) to check for leaks.

Comment: What if you have a private variable with such a helper class in your activity, that holds a `Context` reference?

Comment: @Peterdk if your variable is holding Context instance from getApplicationContext(), no problem. But if you are holding Context from an Activity, take care with memory leaks (more properly holding instance from Activities more than needed). Maybe you should use a WeakReference to hold the Activity context instance and use a listener to know when your application has changed to other activity.

Answer (score 7):

The scope of the HelperClass is only within your onCreate function, so once onCreate executed, your "h" object is no longer needed and subject to garbage collection.

It would be a different story if "h" was a static member - THAT would be a great way to leak memory.