# Get different cells of GridView

Tags: android, gridview, background, cell

I'm trying to change the background color of my GridView. This works perfectly with this code:

```
GridView gv = (GridView) findViewById(R.id.gvSpeelveld);
gv.setBackgroundColor(Color.RED);
```

But now I want to change the color of different cells. For example: Row 2 cell 2 should be blue.
What method should I use to get the GridView item on a specific position to change the color?

I tried with these methods, but it didn't work out well

```
//Attempt 1
gv.getChildAt(1).setBackgroundColor(Color.BLUE);
//Attempt 2 (returns data, not the whole object)
gv.getItemAtPosition(5);
```

So how can I the content of different cells?

Comment: Do that in adpater getView method

Answer (score 1):

It is not a good practice to set the background of a particular list/grid item after execution of the adapter. The best way is to set it in the adapter itself by identifying position.e.g.

```
  class YourAdapter extends BaseAdapter<T>{ ....

 getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent){



 View v = convertView;
       ......



      if(position == your_postion){



                  v.setbackground(Color.parseColor("#FF0000");
            }

        }

     }
```

Comment: And via what way can I identify the position in the adapter?

Comment: U might have used the adapter for the gridview.. so in that adapter u have the method getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent). By ths way u will get position

Comment: I see, but what should I fill in with the properties? int Position is logical, View convertView seems like the GridView but what should be given with the ViewGroup parent?

Comment: I see, but I used the default ArrayAdapter class (ArrayAdapter<String> adapter = 
          new ArrayAdapter<String>(this,android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1,arrSpeelveld);) Is this a problem or should I define my own custom class?

Comment: No.. ArrayAdapter<String> will not satisfy your requirement. You must have to use your custom adapter. please see the link http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6958279/how-to-use-a-custom-arrayadapter-in-a-separate-class

Comment: have u tried matt? if it is worked then please accept the answer

Comment: Not yet. First I'm trying to understand/make a custom adapter that works. Then I'll try to add the colors