# Does using the ViewHolder pattern cause a memory leak after android orientation change?

Tags: android, listview, memory-leaks, android-orientation

From https://developer.android.com/training/improving-layouts/smooth-scrolling.html#ViewHolder

```
> A ViewHolder object stores each of the component views inside the 
> tag field of the Layout, so you can immediately access them without 
> the need to look them up repeatedly.
```

After orientatin change in android a listview is recreated so all listview items
are lost.

Example:

```
/** ViewHolder attached to ListView-Item.tag */
public static class MyViewHolder {
    /** the image belonging to ListView-Item */
    ImageView mListViewItemImage;
}
```

**My question:** does this cause a memory leak because there is a cyclic reference:

- ListView-Item.tag references MyViewHolder
- MyViewHolder.mListViewItemImage references the old gui that was discarded after orientation change.

If this causes a memory leak do i have to implement a ViewHolder garbage collection?

Answer (score 0):

This pattern doesn't use static variables, only the class is a static inner class.

In the reference you mentioned, there's clearly stated that you should create an instance of the `ViewHolder` class like this:

```
ViewHolder holder = new ViewHolder();
```

Then you'll have an instance of the ViewHolder class, which means the Garbage Collector can collect it, thus it won't remain in the memory if there' no more references to it. If the `ViewHolder` instance doesn't have references to it, it can be collected, as well as the objects that have only references from the `ViewHolder` object (the `ImageViews`).

So my general answer: `ViewHolder` pattern if you use it correctly won't cause memory leak.

Comment: memory leak is not limited to static variables. as far as i know android cannot garbagecollect cyclic references like `a.ref = b` and `b.ref= a`

Comment: if `a` is your `ViewHolder` object, and `b` is your `ImageView`: you have a reference from the `ViewHolder` to `ImageView`, but in the `ImageView` you don't have a reference to `ViewHolder`, right? This way no cyclic dependencies. However even if that would be the case, GC is a clever thing, if there are circles which aren't used from anywhere, it finds and destroys them.

Comment: am i wrong if i say that imageview has a reference to activity (getContext()) which has reference to listview  which has reference to listview-items which has reference to viewholder which has reference to imageview? i am not shure if GC is clever enought to resolve this. thats why i asked this question.

Comment: Still your ViewHolder gets collected as there are no more references to it after Android recreates your listview. Android handles the views' gc when the orientation change happens. [Check this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3346080/android-references-to-a-context-and-memory-leaks)