# is it bad to pass a reference of Activity to the service- not causing any trouble

Tags: android

I was trying to update the UI from a service and I thought of passing the reference of `Activity` to the service, like this:

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity{

... onCreate(...){
  //service already connected
  service.register(MainActivity.this);
  }
}  
  
public class service extends Service(){
   private MainActivity mActivity = null;
   public void register(MainActivity activity){
    mActivity = activity;
   }
   public void updateUI(){
      mActivity.getUI_Component().doSomething().update();
   }
}
```

The service created is a `started` and `bound` service so it runs even after the `Activity` is destroyed, so I thought the service would crash if the `updateUI` method is invoked after the activity is destroyed, but **to my surprise it didn't crash**. So, my **first question would be, why did the service not crash even when the UI component was not available**.

I'd probably have to update the activity reference when I regain the UI but, I wonder if this approach is a good enough one to be implemented, many suggest using the `Broadcast Receiver` instead, but if this is ok, I'd really want to use this instead of having to go through the overhead of updating the UI for updating a simple component

EDIT:  we'd update the Activity reference in the service like so:

```
public class MainActivity ...{
   @Override
  public void onResume(){
     service.re_register(MainActivity.this);
   }
}

public class service extends Service(){
 private MainActivity mActivity;
 ...
 public void re_register(MainActivity newActivity){
    mActivity = newActivity;
  }
}
```

EDIT2: Also, is this scenerio a memory leak? When the Activity is destroyed, the `Service` holds a garbage value(an unusable object reference) but, when the `Service` is destroyed, the memory is freed, right? So, I think this might not be a memory leak, but below we have a discussion that it might be, if someone could please clarify this more.

Comment: does it really need a `MainActivity` reference, or a e.g. `UIComponentHolder` provided that `MainActivity implements UIComponentHolder` interface?

Comment: UIComponentHOlder can do, but once MainActivity implements an interface, we're basically still passing the reference to the activity, right? It's just implementing the interface

Comment: Same instance, but completely different thing. `UIComponentHolder` cant actually do `getContext()` or `startActivityForResult` and so on and so on...  but to answer your question - yes, both things will point to the same instance; no, UIComponentHolder is not an activity but the instance you're passing, which would be MainActivity, also happens to be an Activity besides UIComponentHolder.

Comment: As far as leaking is concerned, it's most probably going to leak, so do pinpoint what you actually need in the service and give it just that, instead of "everything" so the service can fetch what it needs from that "everything" (in this case, MainActivity). WeakReference will help. LEakCannary, while nice, can also produce false positives. Try not to keep an activity reference in your service if possible.

Comment: @Shark, 
Also, the service executes on a separate thread, but UI updates are only allowed on the main UI thread, how am I being able to update the UI using the service thread?i.e. I invoke the activity's method from the service thread, how is this being possible?

Comment: The service should fire a LocalBroadcast which should be listened to by some component, or Activity, and then ran on the UI thread.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Why did the service not crash even when the UI component was not
> available?

Since you're holding a reference to the `MainActivity` in your `Service` class, the garbage collector won't collect the activity instance. This will cause a memory leak in your app.

If you want to confirm the behavior, replace your Service class with the following which uses a `WeakReference<MainActivity>`. The below code should throw a `NullPointerException` once the MainActivity goes out of the view (assuming the MainActivity instance gets GC by the time!).

```
public class service extends Service(){

   private WeakReference<MainActivity> mActivity = null;

   public void register(MainActivity activity){
       mActivity = new WeakReference(activity);
   }

   public void updateUI(){
      mActivity.get().getUI_Component().doSomething().update();
   }
}
```

Furthermore, I'd recommend you to take a look at [LeakCanary](https://square.github.io/leakcanary/), which is a great library to help you debug common memory leaks.

> I'd probably have to update the activity reference when I regain the
> UI

It depends on what exactly you're trying to do. I'm assuming you want to restore the UI with the data it previously had. One option is to use the database or in memory data-structure holding the information and restore UI state once it gets created. Please provide more information on your specific use case.

Comment: I do want to restore the UI state,  but I am in this case trying to regain the control to the UI from the service.

Comment: "This will cause a memory leak in your app.", but how will it cause a memory leak? The Activity remains there as long as the service lives, it'll go away once the service is destroyed, right?(because, it's reference in a variable) On top of which, if I update the reference in method like `onResume` then the garbage collector should collect the previous activity class, right?

Comment: I'm considering the scenario, you've activity `A` and service `S` references it. You navigate to activity `B`, and all the views in `A` are not used but it stays in memory because `S` is referencing it. That's where the memory leak is. Didn't quite follow the "update the reference in onResume()" part.

Comment: If the data is not too memory consuming, you can have a singleton `object` which will hold the data. Benefit of that is you can do `DataHolder.save(...)` and `DataHolder.restore()` kind of a thing. You get the idea!

Comment: @SiddhartKamaria , "are not used but it stays in memory because S is referencing it." , but, is this a memory leak? There would be a memory leak if the activity remained in memory, even if `S` is destroyed, isn't it? It's only that the data that it holds is _stale_ , i.e. it's some garbage value, yet it's a valid place holder, and not yet leaked.

Comment: ` you can have a singleton object` , but activities don't have direct constructors, (or do they? I've never used them), and the constructors would have to be private? It could be public, but we gotta keep track of not using it

Comment: That aforementioned scenario would definitely count as a memory leak if the view is not on screen, all views such as button etc. can be safely GC, had the activity not been referenced by the service.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/221220/discussion-between-siddharth-kamaria-and-juztcode).

Comment: @Shark , do you think this scenerio may not be a memory leak?

Comment: I think it's gonna be both a memory leak and a context leak, BUT - use a profiler. what i think is not always how things are. do read about this as well https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3346080/android-references-to-a-context-and-memory-leaks

Comment: Take a look at [this one too](https://medium.com/swlh/context-and-memory-leaks-in-android-82a39ed33002)

Comment: @Shark , I'm really sorry, but I just found out the angle value taken by `view.setRotation(angle)` and view.animate.rotate(angle) are not the same, e.g. -90 rotates clockwise 90 in the former case but in the latter it is counterclockwise, so the rotation was essentially getting nullified. Should'd mentioned that, sorry.