# how is the UI being able to be updated from the service?

Tags: java, android

[With regard to this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63813093/is-it-bad-to-pass-a-reference-of-activity-to-the-service-not-causing-any-troubl?noredirect=1#comment112846257_63813093), basically I register my `MainActivity` to my service( I just pass a reference of my running activity to the service) and update my UI from there. But my confusion is that, if `Service` is a separate thread(not the UI thread) and I'm calling UI updates from the `Service` thread, why is it working? AFAIK , only the UI thread is supposed to be able to call the UI updates, right?

For, reference, I'm just reposting the code from the related post, on how I am updating the UI from the `service`:

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity{

... onCreate(...){
  //service already connected
  service.register(MainActivity.this);
  }
}  
  
public class service extends Service(){
   private MainActivity mActivity = null;
   public void register(MainActivity activity){
    mActivity = activity;
   }
   public void updateUI(){
      mActivity.getUI_Component().doSomething().update();
   }
}
```

Comment: You're working under a false assumption. That `Service` is not a separate thread. Its lifecycle methods will be called on your app's main thread, the UI thread, so unless you're starting your own threads there somewhere, you're already on the right thread.

Comment: really, thank you. If the comment was in the answer section, I'd mark it answered.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Service by default runs on the main thread , that is not at all the issue. And the way you presuming that you simply pass the reference is not a good practice. What you can do is bind to the service and get the service instance prior passing the activity instance.

inside service `onBind` return the service using `LocalBinder` and in the activity use `ServiceConnection` to connect to it

```
protected ServiceConnection mServerConn = new ServiceConnection() {
    @Override
    public void onServiceConnected(ComponentName name, IBinder binder) {
        Log.d(LOG_TAG, "onServiceConnected");
    }

    @Override
    public void onServiceDisconnected(ComponentName name) {
        Log.d(LOG_TAG, "onServiceDisconnected");
    }
}

public void start() {
    // mContext is defined upper in code, I think it is not necessary to explain what is it 
    mContext.bindService(intent, mServerConn, Context.BIND_AUTO_CREATE);
    mContext.startService(intent);
}

public void stop() {
    mContext.stopService(new Intent(mContext, ServiceRemote.class));
    mContext.unbindService(mServerConn);
}
```

Inside your service something like this

```
public class MyBinder extends Binder {
    MyService getService() {
        return MyService.this;
    }
}
```

`onServiceConnected` will return binder instance . use `binder.getService()` and put your working code there.