# How can I handle the click listener inside the static method?

Tags: java, android, android-alertdialog

It is very boring to initialize `AlertDialog` every time I want to use it, I have a lot of activities that use `AlertDialog` so I want to simplify that and create a class to initialize `AlertDialog` and show it when I want.

Here is the `DialogManager` class that I created:

```
public class DialogManager {

    private static AlertDialog.Builder builder;

    public static void show(Context context, int themeResId, String title, String message, String positiveButtonText) {
        builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(context, themeResId)
                .setTitle(title)
                .setMessage(message)
                .setPositiveButton(positiveButtonText, null);
        builder.show();
    }

    public static void show(Context context, int themeResId, String title, String message, String positiveButtonText, String negativeButtonText) {
        builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(context, themeResId)
                .setTitle(title)
                .setMessage(message)
                .setPositiveButton(positiveButtonText, null)
                .setNegativeButton(negativeButtonText, null);
        builder.show();
    }

}
```

Everything works well but I faced a problem with the click listener, How can I handle the click listener because every activity will treat the button in its way.

How can I handle that?

Comment: how are you currently implementing your clicklistener and what stops you form calling a static method?

Comment: @f1sh I'm showing the `AlertDialog` by calling this `DialogManager.show(this, android.R.style.Theme_DeviceDefault_Light_Dialog_Alert, "...", "...", "...");
` and I pass the text of button but actually, that button doesn't do anything because I don't how can I handle it. Every activity will handle the button in its way.

Comment: What do you mean by "I don't how can I handle it"? Does the button have a click listener?

Comment: @f1sh I don't know how can I handle it**. Look at the answer below it is working now as I want and thank you for trying to help me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[`setPositiveButton`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/AlertDialog.Builder#setPositiveButton(int,%20android.content.DialogInterface.OnClickListener)) takes `DialogInterface.OnClickListener` as a second param, so just add it as a method parameter

```
public static void show(Context context, int themeResId, String title, String message,
        String positiveButtonText,
        DialogInterface.OnClickListener positiveCallback) {
    show(context, themeResId, title, message,
        positiveButtonText, positiveCallback,
        null, null); // no negative in this case
}

public static void show(Context context, int themeResId, String title, String message,
        String positiveButtonText,
        DialogInterface.OnClickListener positiveCallback,
        String negativeButtonText,
        DialogInterface.OnClickListener negativeCallback) {
    AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(context, themeResId)
            .setTitle(title)
            .setMessage(message)
            .setPositiveButton(positiveButtonText, positiveCallback);
    if (negativeButtonText!=null) {
        builder.setNegativeButton(negativeButtonText, negativeCallback);
    }
    builder.show();
}
```

and don't overuse `static` keyword, keeping `static` `Builder` on top of this files isn't proper approach (in some cases it may lead to memory leak, probably also in your case), so remove below line and keep only local builder unti you call `builder.show()`

```
private static AlertDialog.Builder builder;
```

Comment: You saved me as usual, This is working perfectly but about your advice, What is the difference if I initialize the `AlertDialog` from an outside method or inside it? I think the same thing

Comment: `static` field/object on top of file is kept as long app process works, even when its not needed anymore (so after `show()` call in your case). it may keep reference to e.g. `Context` (not `Builder` takes it as param), which lead to [memory leak](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3346080/android-references-to-a-context-and-memory-leaks) (probably most common in Android framework)